# NPM Install -- copying Files to other folder

Tags: node.js, npm

It's possible to install a node module in which, It's copy file other folder, like etc.

I mean my app has

```
app.js
conf/config.json

npm install app -g 

conf/config.json--> /etc/app/config.json
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have non trivial tasks to implement, you can benefit from a task framework like [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) or [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/). These are used mostly to automate builds which is basically a non trivial set of file operations.

For simple, one off copies the [copyfiles module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/copyfiles) could be your best friend.

Comment: In fact is not at build process, it is on production

Comment: ok, my answer is still applicable but I rewrote it anyway. Let me know if you need further instructions using these.